# Find the exact length of the curve. $y = 3 + 2x^{\frac{3}{2}}$, $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$

Tags: calculus

Find the exact length of the curve. $y = 3 + 2x^{\frac{3}{2}}$,    $0 ≤ x ≤ 1$

My answer is  from -9.1 to 9.1 [image]

Comment: Please explain how you got your answer. What means can be used to get an answer: Is numeric integration acceptable? And what to you mean by "My answer is from -9.1 to 9.1"? That is far from exact!

Comment: It seems Ben has to feed the result into some system, which is not happy about the answer. So one can guess if it needs more digits or the more complex exact term. Did you get how the problem can be solved?

Comment: BTW a negative curve length seems unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following rule to find the length:

$$\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\right)^2}\space\space\text{d}x$$

---

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(3 + 2x^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\right)^2}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\left(3\sqrt{x}\right)^2}\space\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+9x}\space\space\text{d}x=$$

---

Substitute $u=9x+1$ and $\text{d}u=9\space\space\text{d}x$. New lower bound $u=1+9\cdot 0=1$ and new upper bound $u=1+9\cdot 1=10$:

---

$$\frac{1}{9}\int_{1}^{10}\sqrt{u}\space\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\frac{1}{9}\int_{1}^{10}u^{\frac{1}{2}}\space\space\text{d}u=$$
$$\frac{1}{9}\left[\frac{2u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right]_{1}^{10}=$$
$$\frac{1}{9}\left[\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{u^{\frac{3}{2}}}{1}\right]_{1}^{10}=$$
$$\frac{1}{9}\left[\frac{2}{3}\cdot u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{1}^{10}=$$
$$\frac{2}{27}\left[u^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{1}^{10}=$$
$$\frac{2}{27}\left(10^{\frac{3}{2}}-1^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)=$$
$$\frac{2}{27}\left(10\sqrt{10}-1\right)\approx 2.27$$

---

[image]

Comment: -Jan Erland My answer is 1. I that correct?

Comment: @BenCarson2016 no that is wrong!

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @BenCarson2016 I'm not, I've checked my answer with Mathematica and it gives me exactly the same, so I'm right!!!

Comment: @ Jan Eerland Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: @BenCarson2016 yes it gives me the same

Comment: @ Jan Eerland  What program is that? Can access for free?

Comment: No you can't,it is Mathematica 10

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
ds = \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} = \sqrt{1+ (y')^2} \, dx = \sqrt{1+9x} \, dx
$$
Estimation:

The curve goes through $(0,3)$ and $(1,5)$. The shortest connection is a straight line, having length $\sqrt{1^2+2^2}=\sqrt{5}=2.23\cdots$. The path over the sides has length $1+2=3$. So we have
$$
2.23\le s \le 3
$$
as estimation.